# Conditionally compiling a single file with CMake flag

Tags: c++, build, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have an option that will compile different versions of a single file in my codebase depending on whether it's set to ON or OFF.

That file is part of a target that includes many other files that need to be compiled to create an executable.

Currently, if I re-run CMake and set the flag to ON or OFF, the target is rebuilt, and that forces all file objects to be rebuilt as well. However, only one file is changed by the flag, which means that I have to wait for all of them to be rebuilt, although only rebuilding that one would suffice.

My question is: Is there some way, without defining a new target to only re-compile a specific file when the flag changes?

Comment: Rerunning cmake touches all the makefiles it generated. That's more likely the cause of the rebuild.

Comment: CMake may assume that your file is completly different and so will rebuild every source file that contains references to this file.

Comment: Why not configure targets for both versions (an `ON` and an `OFF` version) with CMake? Then, you can choose which version to build when you run `make`.

Comment: @D.Nathanael CMake doesn't build anything.  It's not a build tool.  CMake will regenerate the project files (e.g Visual Studio project) and the build tool (e.g MSbuild) will notice that things are out of date and will cause a rebuild.